# Using Rsync to SSH and Find files

Tags: ssh, find, rsync

Hello I am trying to use Rsync to SSH into a remote server and pull a certain type of file that has been modified within the last 24 hours.

Here is what I am trying:

```
rsync -avx --timeout=480 --ignore-existing admin@remote:'`find /results/analysis/output/Home/ -mtime -1 -name "*.[fastq]"`' /Users/remote_user/Documents/Repository/
```

This gives me "permission denied" errors.  Anybody know what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: If `admin` owns all the files in the tree, then the permission could probably a directory without an executable bit attached to it (i.e. accidental `chmod 644 dirname`)

Comment: both the target and destination are listed as 4096

Comment: @Sam - you need to look at the first bit, it probably should be something like this (from `ls -l`): `drwxr-xr-x.  4 admin admin    4096 Jan 26 16:13`.

Comment: check the permission settings of local directory /Users/remote_user/Documents/Repository